# dict of dict to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dict of dict following the format:

```
{ row_name : { column_name : column_value } }
```

I want to convert this dictionary into a pandas dataframe:

```
row_name1 | column_name1.1  | column_name1.2   | column_name1.3   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
row_name1 | column_value1.1 | column_value1.2  | column_value1.3  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
row_name2 | column_name2.1  | column_name2.2   | column_name2.3   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
row_name2 | column_value2.1 | column_value2.2  | column_value 2.3 |
```

Or something similar. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataFrame.from_dict` does this, in your case the `orient` argument needs to be `'index'` rather than `'columns'` since you have row keys in the outer dictionary:

```
dd = {'rowA': {'colA': 1, 'colB': 2},
      'rowB': {'colA': 3, 'colB': 4}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dd, orient='index')
df
Out[10]: 
      colB  colA
rowA     2     1
rowB     4     3
```